# How to show 404 page for not found images

Tags: 7

If I request an image that doesn't exist like mysite.com/test/test_not_found_image.jpg, I get a Not Found white page just like this page: https://www.drupal.org/files/testing_404.jpg.

Is it possible to have Drupal show the styled 404 page that I have instead of that white 404 page?

Comment: I think it is done by changing the values in .htaccess. I have been able to create my own customized micro-CMS where I either redirect to 404 page or homepage for not found files, including images, and it is controlled via .htaccess. I have tried to replicate the behaviour with Drupal 7 but haven't been successful. Maybe this could help you: https://www.drupal.org/node/15366#comment-7218780

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @Shawn Conn's answer does work it does cause issues in Drupal because of image cache. If you go to a page that doesn't have the image style created yet it won't create the image because of the .htaccess rule.

The best way to display a 404 page on bad images is to use the [Fast 404](https://www.drupal.org/project/fast_404) module and create a static html page.

Comment: Can confirm. I thought ImageCache generated images on save, but it's on request URL for both [D7](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/modules/image/image.module?h=7.44#n83) & [D8](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/core/modules/image/src/Routing/ImageStyleRoutes.php?h=8.1.4#n53).